# Using dates in Flot

Tags: flot

I need help displaying flot chart (search in similar thread does not work for me):

```
var graphData = [{
data: [ [1343772000*1000,130],[1343858400*1000,152]...
data: [ [1312149600*1000,202],[1312236000*1000,165]...
```

and

```
xaxis: {
mode: "time",
timeformat: "%d.%m",
minTickSize: [1, "day"]
},
```

The result is something like...
[image]

How can i display the correct dates in x-axis ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by correct.

If you're talking about the x-axis label format, then the %d.%m timeformat that you're using tells Flot to show the number of the month followed by the day, which is exactly what appears in your screenshot.

If you want month names instead of numbers, you need to provide the 'monthNames' option, containing 12 strings, i.e. `["January, "February", ...]`.  Then you can use the %b format option to use the appropriate string.  For more info on all the available format options see the [time series data](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) section of the docs.

Regarding the gap in the middle of the plot, that also appears correct.  The timestamps in your first series start at August 2012, while the ones in the second series start at August 2011. If each series covers three months, then one would expect to see exactly what is shown in your screenshot.

If neither answer is relevant, then you need to provide more information about your data and what you expect to see.

Comment: The data contains values within 3 months. The middle of the plot is empty.

Comment: The series covers three months (you are right), all timestamps are correctly set, data contains values also in the middle. But there is still a gap showing nothing. I expect to see in x-axis 1.8. 5.8 10.8 ...1.9. 5.9.... etc etc

Comment: It seems, that my data are from different years - so first set is 2011 and second is from 2012. How can i overlay the 3 month so that flot displays no gap between ?

Comment: You can either subtract 9 months (a little over 23328000000) from the second set of dates, or maybe provide a custom tickFormatter to produce ticks with a gap in the range.